# MVC reload Parent View from Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am developing an `MVC` Application. I have a `Parent View` that contains a `Partial View`.

`Partial View` has a `submit` function that calls a `Controller Method`.

If anything goes wrong I need to retrieve Error Message. If everything goes OK, I want to reload Parent View.

In the begining I had a

> @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "javascript:return validate()" }))

in `Partial View`. So when everything goes OK, I can call a Method to reload Parent View

> return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = Id });

but I can not retrieve an Error Message.

So in order to retrieve an Error Message, and stay in the same View. I have to use Json.

So I use

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Controller")" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

and define an

> $('form').submit(function (event)

to do the call to the Controller. But I can not Redirect to another Method to reload Parent View.

My parent View have a model like

> @model long

that is the ID of the current record.

When I redirect to another method. the Method do this...

```html
 public ActionResult Create(Id =0)
        {
            return View(Id);
        }
```

If I do `window.location.href =ParentView` .. I do not have the ID generated.

the only thing I can do is call another Controller Method and set

```
$('#div).html(result)
```

But I need to set a DIV in my Parent View. I do not want to do that. I am looking another way to do it.

What it the correct way to reach boths things?

thanks

Comment: use $.ajax method...to pass data to controller in JsonResult or ActionResult and that method return json data and u check that data in success method...

Comment: Agree with @DhirenPatel.  Then you determine how to proceed after the ajax returns.  Most often the parent page refresh is a javascript `window.location.href = ...`

Comment: yes, but I want to reload Parent View on Controller Method. I only returns json if an error occurs. I am trying to do a Redirect to another Method if everything is ok..

Comment: When i reload Parent View, I need to pass a parameter that is the ID of the current record... how can i do that using window.location.href= ?

Comment: for passing parameter use can make ViewModel in javascript and pass to controller and use that link that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260758/asp-net-mvc-ajax-call-return-error-message-in-parallel-with-partial-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to pass id value using `window.location.href` you can do as below:

```
 window.location.href = '../Controller/Create?id=' + 1;
```

Here `1` is the `id` passed to param `id` in Create action.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, pass back an object with a boolean for success. If successful, in the AJAX call, use a redirect URL to call the other controller method.

```js
$.post(url,
    {
      PartId: $("#PartID").val(),
      SubscriptionId: $("#SubscriptionId").val()
    })
    .done(function (result) {
      if (result.Saved === true) {
        $.get(urlredirect,
        ).done(function (result) {
        })
      }
    });
}
```